# Building the HTML for a linked image with a JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript

I've written this code:

```
var ac = $('<a href ='img'> <img src ='img'> </a>').appendTo("#2");
```

The error is that for the browser I must close the parentheses after having closed the single quotes and then end the statement with a semicolon.

Example:

```
var ac = $('<a href =');img('> <img src =');img('> </a>').appendTo("#2");
```

How can I write the statement to include the JavaScript variable `img` in the HTML code?

Comment: Use escape sequence. img is a variable or string?

Comment: But 'img' is not a string, is the variable. ( i also  will edit the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> you have to concatenate your variable

```
var ac = $('<a href ="' + img + '"> <img src ="' + img + '"> </a>').appendTo("#2");
```

Comment: Thanks, now run well :D

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `'` and `''` properly. It is JS syntax parser error. Below will fix it:

```
var ac = $("<a href ='img'> <img src ='img'> </a>").appendTo("#2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use backpacks (``` `` ```) and `${}` for string interpolation:

```
var ac = $(`<a href='${img}'><img src='${img}'></a>`).appendTo("#2");
```